# Retrieve several words in the string in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a string like '(ST1) today is Tuesday,(ST2)--CCC,yao (ST3)'.I would like to retrieve all words that start with ST and then insert into a temp table. In this case, the temp table will have 3 rows, include ST1, ST2, and ST3. Is there any good way to achieve this goal? Thank you. I am using SQL Server 2008 and T-SQL is my language.

Comment: Define what you mean by word. How do you know where one "word" begins and ends.

Comment: Are desired values located between opening and ending parentheses?

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry I did not mention it clearly. One word should between opening and ending parentheses.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader Yes, you are right.

Comment: Then look at my answer. That is what I assumed to be the case given your sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each "word" is what you have in between parenthesis you can use a string splitter for this quite easily. I am using the splitter from Jeff Moden at sql server central.com. You can find an article, discussion and code here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

There are plenty of other great splitters out there. Aaron Bertrand has an excellent article and collection of them here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

```
declare @SomeString varchar(100) = '(ST1) today is Tuesday,(ST2)--CCC,yao (ST3)'

select s.Item
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(replace(@SomeString, ')', '('), '(') s
where Item like 'ST%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also grab a copy of [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) and do this:

```
DECLARE @yourstring varchar(100) = '(ST1) today is Tuesday,(ST2)--CCC,yao (ST3)';

SELECT item = SUBSTRING(token, 2, 3)
FROM dbo.NGrams8k(@yourstring, 5)
WHERE token LIKE '(%)';
```

**EDIT: How to handle values longer than 3:**

```
DECLARE @yourstring varchar(100) = '(ST1) today is Tuesday,(ST2)--CCC,yao (ST11)!! (ST999)';

WITH gramSizes(s,ng) AS (SELECT 3, 5 UNION ALL SELECT 4, 6 UNION ALL SELECT 5, 7)
SELECT item = SUBSTRING(token, 2, s)
FROM gramSizes
CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(@yourstring, ng)
WHERE token LIKE '(%)'AND token NOT LIKE '%) '
```

Results:

```
item
-----
ST1
ST2
ST11
ST999
```

Comment: That's pretty clever Alan. Not sure how I missed your article on this but one I am definitely adding to my toolbox!! The only downside here is if the "words" are longer than 3 characters this will not return them. But if all of the words are exactly 3 characters this works and has a much simpler execution plan.

Comment: Thanks for your help as well. Alan

Comment: You're welcome Iverson. Sean - thanks for the kind words. I meant to include an example for values longer than 3. I just now updated my answer.